# Аннотация и рефакторинг

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть `module_0` где хранится, пока не определенная переменная, для примера `tk`:

```
tk: 'tk.Tk()' = None
```

Есть `module_1`, где определяется `tk`:

```
import module_0
module_0.tk = tk.Tk()
```

Есть `module_2`, где используется `tk`:

```
import module_0
module_0.tk.after() # тут не понимает что tk это tk.Tk()
```

PyCharm не понимает, что в tk лежит `tk.Tk()`, например не продолжает `.after`, но продолжает `.StringVar` и др. С пользовательскими классами вообще не понимает анотацию. Все последних версий.

Как изменить так, чтобы работал рефакторинг?

Comment: Кажется, вы неверно понимаете значение слова "рефакторинг"

Comment: Ну и вы же импортируете tk из module_0. Почему вы ожидаете, что PyCharm будет учитывать значение из module_1 ?

Comment: я ожидаю что он использует анотацию из module_0, которая для пользовательских классов не работает совсем

Answer (score 0):

У меня нет на рабочем компьютере ткинтера, и я не могу воспроизвести именно ваш код.

Но, насколько я могу смоделировать ситуацию на других классах, ваша проблема в следующем:

Аннотация переменных требует в качестве типа именно тип. А не экземпляр этого типа.

Вы же в качестве аннотации передаёте именно экземпляр типа tk.Tk (на что явно указывают круглые скобки). Попробуйте убрать из аннотации круглые скобки - и всё должно заработать:

```
tk: 'tk.Tk' = None
```